# count and say using recursion in C++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

Given 'n', the problem is to generate the nth sequence of Count and Say.
[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/look-and-say-sequence/) is the problem description.

I was trying to solve this through recursion:

**Edit:**
Basically iterating through the string and counting consecutive 1s,2s(or whatever) and appending (count+that number we counted)(it's a string, by the way) to the main string which is to be returned ultimately.
And the link works now.

```
string gofind(int N){
    if(N==1) return "1";
    else{
        string temp = gofind(N-1);
        ostringstream str1;
        string* t  = &(temp);
        int count;
        string n;
        while(*t!="\0"){
            count=1;
            while(*t==*(t+1)) {
                count++;
                t++;
            }
            str1<<count;//basically to convert int to str
            string geek = str1.str();
            n.append(geek+*t);
            t++;
        }
        return n;
    }
}
```

This throws up an exception during runtime "bad_alloc".There are probably a lot of things wrong in this code. 
Could somebody point out what? And what could be the correct recursive solution.

Comment: I highly recommend you learning how to use a debugger and how to debug your programs. A good debugger lets you step through your code line by line and inspect values of the variables, which is really helpful in deducing where the problem lies

Comment: It seems you're treating `t` as a `char *`, not a `string *`.

Comment: This is not a good use of recursion. You can just iterate, and remember the previous line.

Comment: The link you gave does not work.

Comment: @Jeffrey Could you elaborate why? I thought this was somewhat similar to the factorial problem, and so I followed this approach instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a correct way to iterate through a string:

```
string* t  = &(temp); // Please no!
while(*t!="\0"){
```

This gives you a pointer to where the `string` stores its control block, i.e. information like its size etc. - this is **not** where the character data is. Also, you are treating this pointer as if there was an array of `strings`s there, not an array of characters (it is neither).

You can iterate through the string by simply indexing it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp.size() - 1; ++i)
{
  count = 1;
  while ((i+1 < temp.size()) && (temp[i] == temp[i+1]))
  {
    count++;
    i++;
  }
}
```

I think you can work out the full solution from here.

Comment: Given that the user already acknowledged that their code may contain several major mistakes, I thought it instructionary to emphasize the gravity of that particular issue. But I have followed your suggestion and removed the emphasis in accordance with your comparison. Feel free to suggest other wordings.

Comment: I like it better now. And my respect for taking my criticism in such a matter-of-fact way.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Thank you so much. That was really silly, and yes, misguided.

Comment: Solved the issue. And the solution now works just fine :D

Answer (score 1):

```
string gofind(int N){
    if(N==1) return "1";
    if(N==2) return "11";
    else{
        string temp = gofind(N-1);
        int count;
        string n;
        for (int i=0;i<temp.size();i++){
            count=1;
            while((temp[i]==temp[i+1])&&(i<temp.size()-1)){
                i++;
                count++;
            }
            ostringstream str1;//all of  this to
            str1<<count;//basically to convert 
            string geek = str1.str();//int to str
            n.append(geek+temp[i]);
        }
        return n;
    }
}
```

This is the corrected code ,by the way.

Answer (score 0):

#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void func(string s,int p){

```
if((s.substr(1)).length()==0){
    return;
}
if(s[0]==s[1]){
    p=p+1;
    func(s.substr(1),p);
}
if(s[0]!=s[1]){
    cout<<p<<s[0];
    func(s.substr(1),p=1);
}
if((s.substr(1)).length()==1){
    cout<<p<<s[1];
}
```

}

int main(){

```
string s;
cin>>s;
func(s,1);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).